# Не создается файл bundle.js

Tags: node.js, webpack, babel, webpack-dev-server

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь собрать проект с помощью Webpack. Проект собирается, никаких ошибок не возникает. На страницу захожу. Но, при просмотре с(F12) в директории Sources нет файла bundle.js, а есть только моя html страничка и файл css. Стек Node.js + Express+ React+ MongoDB. Все npm последней версии. Пути которые указанные в конфиге соответствуют действительности. При сборке никаких ошибок нет.

Файл package.json

```
{
  "name": "medical-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "medical application",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start_server": "babel-node server/app.js",
    "webpack-devserver": "webpack-dev-server --debug --hot --devtool eval-source-map --output-pathinfo --watch --colors --inline --content-base public --port 8090 --host localhost"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "url": ""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.17.1",
    "express": "^4.15.2",
    "less": "^2.7.2",
    "mongoose": "^4.9.1",
    "react": "^15.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^15.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.24.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015":"^6.24.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.27.3",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.16.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "^2.3.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.4.2"
  }
}
```

WebPack

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: ["./client/main.js"],
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/public/build/',
        publicPath: "build/",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                exclude: [/node_modules/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.less$/,
                loader: "style-loader!css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!less",
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                loader: "react-hot!babel",
                exclude: [/node_modules/, /public/]
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json-loader",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала, посмотрите, появляется ли в `/public/build/` `bundle.js` после билда.

Если он там есть, то проверьте, как вы его подключаете к html, вероятно там ошибка в путях.

Если его там нет, то значит бабель его не собирает. Попробуйте установить бабелю пресеты для сборки реакта (возможно вы используете es6 синтаксис или что-нибудь еще в таком духе)

```
  loaders: [
    {
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel',
      query: {"presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]}
    },
    ...
```