# Не создается файл bundle.js при помощи webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel

Пытаюсь собрать проект с помощью Webpack. Проект собирается, никаких ошибок не возникает. Однако и файл bundle.js не создается. Что я делаю не так?

Файл package.json:

```
    {
  "name": "ezsadmin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Административная панель",
  "main": "webpack.config.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "webpack --watch"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "ssh://werfwerfwe"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.14",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.30.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.13.13",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.2"
  }
}
```

Файл webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry: './assets/js/main.js',
    module: {
        rules: [
          { test: /\.svg$/, use: 'svg-inline-loader' },
          { test: /\.css$/, use: [ 'style-loader', 'css-loader' ] },
          { test: /\.(js)$/, use: 'babel-loader' }
        ],
      },    
    output: {
      filename: 'bundle.js', 
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/public/js/')
    },
    mode: 'production'    
};
```

Файл babel.config.json:

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-react", "@babel/preset-env"],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx"]
}
```

Сюда [Не создается файл bundle.js](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/644759/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-bundle-js) смотрел - не понял.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка в

```
path: path.resolve(__dirname, '/public/js/')
```

Файл создавался, но в корне жесткого диска.